# Benefits of checking password complexity by keyspace instead of character classes used?

Tags: security, passwords

### Question:

What would be the drawbacks of checking a password for keyspace instead of just checking for length and character classes used?

### Details:

I've started to use phrases as passwords and more often than not I hit a wall with user-friendliness because password requirements block my passwords. Even worse, I've run into systems that have password length limits or don't accept spaces, etc.

For instance, take the standard password checker that wants at least 8 characters, 1 number, 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 symbol. If I want my password to be "stackoverflow is the best website ever" the checker would throw up an error yet the keyspace of my passphrse is significantly larger than the basic requirement.

```
"C0mplex?"                               => 6.0956893 × 10^15
"stackoverflow is the best website ever" => 2.4650347 × 10^54
```

As I've had to design systems like this myself, I've started to explore the idea of checking the keyspace size of the password and requiring a minimum keyspace instead of specific traits (as well as common/obvious password checks of course). This way, it doesn't matter if you use an 8-character mixed-symbol password or a 12-character case-insensitive alphanumeric password, they both pass the complexity check.

Any thoughts/caveats you guys can see?

Comment: Interesting question, but voting to close as off-topic. See also: http://xkcd.com/936 :-)

Comment: Pretty sure something very similar was asked before (I'll have to find the link). The conclusion was, even _IF_ the attack knew how you created the password (i.e. short substitution vs long phrases), that phrases would very quickly beat a shorter password with more characters, even in the face of dictionary attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no drawbacks other than the fact that it's harder to write code that checks for keyspace requirements than to check for character classes, and so most websites (which let's face it are not built by brilliant security experts or coders) don't bother.

Worse - passwords which are restricted to maximum lengths are usually because they're storing your password in the database in the clear and have a fixed length column for the storage, which as anyone with even a brief understanding of security will know is unacceptable since passwords should be salted and hashed on the server.